# Split Variable on white space

Tags: perl, split

I'm trying to split a string into an array with the split occurring at the white spaces. Each block of text is seperated by numerous (variable) spaces.

Here is the string:

```
NUM8         host01    1,099,849,993  1,099,849,992             1
```

I have tried the following without success.

```
my @array1 = split / /, $VAR1;

my @array1 = split / +/, $VAR1;

my @array1 = split /\s/, $VAR1;

my @array1 = split /\s+/, $VAR1;
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
$array1[0] = NUM8
$array1[1] = host01
$array1[2] = 1,099,849,993
$array1[3] = 1,099,849,992
$array1[4] = 1
```

What is the best way to split this?

Comment: The last option should work, so my guess is you have some tabs in there possibly.

Comment: What output did you get from your attempts? Last method you used is supposed to work.

Comment: @squiguy: `\s` matches tabs. The problem is that Perl will return a list with a zero-length leading field if the string starts with a separator.

Comment: Here's a radical idea: read the documentation: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If the first argument to `split` is the string ' ' (the space), it is special. It should match whitespace of any size:

```
my @array1 = split ' ', $VAR1;
```

(BTW, it is almost equivalent to your last option, but it also removes any leading whitespace.)

Answer (score 11):

Just try using:

```
my @array1 = split(' ',$VAR1);
```

[**Codepad Demo**](http://codepad.org/U0bo0JlB)

From [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> As another special case, split emulates the default behavior of the
>   command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a literal
>   string composed of a single space character (such as ' ' or "\x20" ,
>   but not e.g. / / ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is
>   removed before splitting occur

Answer (score 8):

`\s+` matches 1 or more whitespaces, and split on them

```
my @array1 = split /\s+/, $VAR1;
```

Comment: works as well. Perhaps my output varied while I was testing so it threw me off. Seems all the answers here work.